# Where is the obj folder of my visual studio 2010 project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, c#-4.0, program-entry-point

I am new to Visual Studio. I am using VS 2010 and I cannot find the main method of my C# application. After browsing a bit, I found out that it is created during the compilation phase and is located in obj/{Debug/Release} folder. However, I am unable to locate the folder on my system.

My solution explorer and properties window look like this:
[image: Solution explorer]

And the corresponding directory (path from the properties window in the above picture) doesn't have obj folder.
[image]

Can somebody help me locate the obj folder? I want to check the flow of my program.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try pressing "Show-All" files in your "Solution Explorer" ribbon bar? (of course after compiling your project and `selecting` "Solution")

Comment: Your main entry point of your **web application** is `Default.aspx.cs`, which is accessible from the solution explorer.  Each time the project is compiled, the contents of the `obj` folder will be overwritten.  That aside, what is the actual question you have?  It sound like you are **very** new to this - maybe the best place to go is here: http://www.asp.net/web-forms

Comment: @BrendanGreen: I wouldn't call `Default.aspx.cs` an entry point in the same way that a `Main` method is - surely that's just the default page if you visit the site without a specific URL... and it won't be involved if someone goes straight to `Login.aspx` for example.

Comment: @JonSkeet right - attempted to simplify things.  Your posted answer is quite good and to the point.

Comment: @ANewGuyInTown Actually, I couldn't find the option of Show-All in the solution explorer. I am using VS2010.

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to `highlight' the project (not solution) and it won't appear if your project is a *WebSite*.

Answer (score 3):

> I cannot find the main method of my C# application

A web site doesn't have a "main" method. It usually has global initialization hooks, but nothing quite like Main.

It also looks like you've created a "Web Site" project rather than a "Web Application" project - I've never fully understood the difference, but I suspect you may find that a web site project isn't built in quite the same way, so you may never see the output folders you were expecting. In particular, I'm not seeing anything that would correspond to where I'd *expect* those initialization hooks to be. You may wish to create a new project as an ASP.NET web application instead.

(I'd update to a more modern version of Visual Studio at the same time, if you possibly can. There's a "community" edition of VS2013 or the release candidate for VS2015...)

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for your answer. I have to create a claimsaware website to talk to the ADFS server and get claims from it. I could find the option of creating one only on VS2010 "new website" option. For the above website, how do I know the flow of the application? Should I try and understand web.config?

Comment: @Anvesha: I'm not sure what you mean by "the flow of the application" - but it sounds like you may just have the web edition of VS... Maybe try the VS2013 Community edition to give more options?

Comment: Just to know the sequence of execution of the files. Actually, after integrating it with ADFS, web.config changes and it is giving me an error. I am trying to figure the sequence in which the files (default.aspx.cs/login.aspx.cs/SampleVaidator.cs) are executed. Does it make sense? Is it possible to know that?

Comment: @Abvesha: No, it doesn't make sense to think in those terms - because it depends which page the user visits. You should think in terms of what executes for each page.

Answer (score 1):

You have created an empty `WebSite` not `WebApplication` so by default in `WebSite` there is no `bin` folder until and unless you explicitly add `bin` folder or you `Add Reference` to dll;

In `WebSite` your main folder for code is `App_Code` folder where all your `.cs` files are placed.And in `WebApplication` all of your code is converted in a `dll` that is placed in `bin` folder.

Comment: Hi Mairaj, do I need to add the bin folder? And what do you mean by an empty website and not a web application? Is there anyway I can understand the flow of the program?

Comment: If you need a bin folder than add it. And you can search on internet that What is difference between Webiste and WebApplication.

Comment: One of the answers on StackOverflow says web application talks to the user but a website doesn't. But my project takes in login information from the user and displays the claims. I really don't get the difference.  And, I just want to know the flow of the project. Will adding the bin folders help me by any chance? I was basically looking for the obj folder which has App.g.i.cs (containing main method) as suggested in some other answer.

Comment: Have a look here http://www.webblogsforyou.com/difference-website-vs-web-application-which-is-best/

Comment: Or search on net with this "difference between website and web application";